# How to Log / Debug variable value in global.asax aspx IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

I have a project using global.asax in ASPX Web. When i'm debug on my local, there's no problem, i can get result value from queryParam. The problem is when i deploy this into IIS remote server.. It always redirect me to home.aspx. So i want to know what is the value of my **result** variable.

How can i debug / console log this on the remote server? So i can know what is the value of my result variable

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string result = Request.QueryString["queryParam"];
   if (result == null)
   {
     Response.Redirect("home.aspx");}
   else{
     Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");}
   }
}
```

I've tried using `Debug.Write()`, but i dont know where to find the result.

Comment: _"How can i debug / console log this on the remote server?"_ - Use the VS Remote Debugger.

Comment: Also your C# as-posted has mismatched `}` braces.

Comment: I don't know of any really "elegant" solution. A few (untested) ideas from the top of my head: (1) use `Trace.WriteLine` and [debugview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), (2) use `File.AppendAllText` (make sure the App Pool user has write permissions), (3) write to the database, if your app uses one, (4) set a Response header and read it with the F12 network tab of your browser (don't know if this will work or if Response.Redirect messes up previously set headers).

Comment: Since you mentioned `Debug.Write`: That should also show up in debugview, but only if you compiled your app in debug mode. `Trace.Write` also works in a release build.